# Cron task with reading .bashrc in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, cron, sh

How to easely  and elegantly pass environment variables from **.bashrc** to cron task?

I've read lots of examples but it seems it doesn't work for me somehow. Why I cannot execute cron task with loaded environment variables from .bashrc or .bashprofile in **bash shell**? I only could able to succeed using **sh shell**. Tested on 2 Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS bionic and Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS xenial.

```
MAILTO=root HOME=/
BASH_ENV=/root/.bashrc

SHELL=/bin/bash
*/1 * * * * . $BASH_ENV; echo $EDITOR > /var/log/supervisor/out.log 2>&1 --> **Doesn't work**

SHELL=/bin/sh
*/1 * * * * . $BASH_ENV; echo $EDITOR > /var/log/supervisor/out.log 2>&1 --> **WORKS**

SHELL=/bin/sh
*/1 * * * * source $BASH_ENV; echo $EDITOR > /var/log/supervisor/out.log 2>&1 --> **Doesn't work**

SHELL=/bin/sh
BASH_ENV=/root/.my_env
*/1 * * * * echo $EDITOR > /var/log/supervisor/out.log 2>&1 --> **WORKS**
```

There are much more that I tried and I kinda nothing can do to just be able to elegantly use (without writing handed made sctipt with source .bashrc) The best answer would be just to use **BASH_ENV** on .bashrc but it only works with my hand-written env files.

Also I've found the line in **.bashrc** that tells. Maybe it somehow conflicts and doesn't read **.bashrc** in bash shell. But why it works with sh shel?.

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

That will stop the evaluation of the file if it is running in a non-interactive shell

Maybe people who were able to easely execute .bashrc used not Ubuntu distros.

I found that [stefanmaric's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64387/can-not-successfully-source-bashrc-from-a-shell-script/77053#77053) was helpful in Ubuntu case but 
`eval "$(cat ~/.bashrc | tail -n +10)"` is super ugly and complicated way of bypassing it

Comment: As which user are you running this cron? Also, is this a users cronjob file or `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.d`?

Comment: On top of that, no need to write `*/1` but `*` is enough.

Comment: And yes `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` is not the way to go. Maybe have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

Comment: @kvantour I'm running all under root ( inside my docker container). All is edited under user's crontab). Just write crontab -e